# C# - Adding multiple pages to PDF file using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

i'm having troubles with my code. I've been looking in StackOverflow here, but it seems the examples doesn't apply to my code.

I've been trying to generate a pdf file with multiple pages but I can't find a way to make it work.

I mean, with the code as is it now, it generates multiple pdf files with the correct data.

Could you help me?

```js
 foreach (var item in ListCars.OrderBy(x => x.Destiny))
                {
                    Document Document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 15f, 0f);
                    Image Img = null;
                    FileStream fsData = null;
                    Img = Image.GetInstance(Properties.Resources.CMODEL, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                    Img.ScaleToFit(PageSize.A4);
                    Img.Alignment = Image.UNDERLYING | Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    string DataForTest = "";
                    string PDFName = "TEST - " + item.Vin + ".PDF";

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Rems\Pages\");
                    fsData = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Rems\Pages\" + PDFName, FileMode.Create);
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document, fsData);

                    Document.Open();

                    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

                    Phrase DataForTestT = new Phrase(DataForTest, FontFactory.GetFont("IMPACT", 8));
                    ct.SetSimpleColumn(DataForTestT, 115, 824, 561, 307, 8, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    ct.Go();

                    Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Rems\Pages\" + PDFName);
                    Document.Add(Img);
                    Document.AddCreationDate();
                    Document.Close();
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307749/creating-multiple-page-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? I'm kinda new with all this stuff.

Comment: Please post the error. What happens? Crashes? Doesn't add pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change `Document Document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 15f, 0f);` to `Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 15f, 0f);`.

Let's figure it out step by step.

You can't set an instance name as it's class name.
Like this:

```
 foreach (var item in ListCars.OrderBy(x => x.Destiny))
                {
                    Document document= new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 15f, 0f);
                    Image Img = null;
                    FileStream fsData = null;
                    Img = Image.GetInstance(Properties.Resources.CMODEL, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                    Img.ScaleToFit(PageSize.A4);
                    Img.Alignment = Image.UNDERLYING | Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    string DataForTest = "";
                    string PDFName = "TEST - " + item.Vin + ".PDF";

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Rems\Pages\");
                    fsData = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Rems\Pages\" + PDFName, FileMode.Create);
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fsData);

                    document.Open();

                    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

                    Phrase DataForTestT = new Phrase(DataForTest, FontFactory.GetFont("IMPACT", 8));
                    ct.SetSimpleColumn(DataForTestT, 115, 824, 561, 307, 8, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    ct.Go();

                    Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Rems\Pages\" + PDFName);
                    document.Add(Img);
                    document.AddCreationDate();
                    document.Close();
                }
```

Comment: It doesn't crash, just ignore the code completely.

I'll do now what you told me there.

Ah i know what you mean there, that was a typo when I was writing the code here.

Comment: Also don't forget to switch the other `Documents` in the necessary places. Paste what i posted.

Comment: Nono, that was just a typo when I was writing the code here. Don't mind it.